# How do I use the 15.10 menu in Ubuntu Studio in 16.04?

Tags: appearance

I have one PC with Ubuntu Studio upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 and another one with Ubuntu Studio 16.04 from the scratch.

My foolish question is about the main menu appearance.

Into the upgraded system, I still have the old 15.10 menu style, which is very comfortable to me. But, the other PC (16.04 version) has the new appearance, which isn't full comfortable to me.

So, the question is: Is there a way to get the old (15.10) menu appearance in the new 16.04?

How?